# Is there a way to route all urls with same base url segment to the same page in Gatsby?

Tags: gatsby

I want site.com/shop/plp/, site.com/shop/plp/whatever-url, and site.com/shop/plp/whatever-url?id:value to all go to site.com/shop/plp, without altering the url or query string.

I'm currently using Gatsby and @reach/router.

Is there a way to accomplish this without resorting to a redirect?

Comment: Your question is too vague. What do you mean without redirect? Is this excluded? https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-link/#how-to-use-the-navigate-helper-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer by Advait got me heading in the right direction, wanted to add the actual code and one additional change that was required.

In gatsby-node.js, before exports.createPages...

```
exports.onCreatePage = ({ page, actions }) => {
    const { createPage } = actions;

    if (page.path === '/routing/') {
        page.matchPath = '/routing/*';
        createPage(page);
    }
};
```

In pages/routing/index.js

```
render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
        <Layout>
            <Container>
                <TestComponent />
            </Container>
        </Layout>
    );
}
```

And the final step to prevent flashing of 404 page before rendering the actual page, related to this issue, https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/5329

In 404.js

```
const browser = typeof window !== "undefined" && window;
const NotFoundPage = () => {
return (
    browser && (
        <div>
            <Layout>
                <Container>
                    <h1>404 Page</h1>
                </Container>
            </Layout>
        </div>
    )
);
};
```

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this with **[Client-only routes](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/client-only-routes-and-user-authentication/)**. Basically it's a front-end solution built into Gatsby that uses a specific file from pages `src/pages/foo.js` for all URLs that match a certain pattern.

I've got a working version of just this specific issue [deployed here](https://advaitju.github.io/gatsby-trial/) - [Github repo](https://github.com/advaitju/gatsby-trial). Try navigating to any URLs with `/app/...` to fetch data from [JSON placeholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) - check the console output. Some examples:

- https://advaitju.github.io/gatsby-trial/app/posts
- https://advaitju.github.io/gatsby-trial/app/comments/
- https://advaitju.github.io/gatsby-trial/app/comments/3

It depends on your static hosting if client-only routes work properly:

- For example, it worked on https://zeit.co/ only if I **first** navigated to a statically generated page (like index `/`) and then navigated to `/app`
- It just works on Github pages. Test before you consider using AWS S3, Google hosting etc.

Look at these files:

- https://github.com/advaitju/gatsby-trial/blob/master/gatsby-node.js
- https://github.com/advaitju/gatsby-trial/blob/master/src/pages/app.js
- https://github.com/advaitju/gatsby-trial/blob/master/src/pages/404.js

Comment: Advait, that was the right direction, thanks, wanted to point out your link to github repo 404's. In addition to client only routes the 404.js needed updating otherwise it would flash the 404 page prior to rendering.

Comment: Woops! My apologies, it was set to private. You can see the code now. This solution relies on 404.js being loaded - that's why it didn't work on Zeit, they had a custom 404. I think frontend routing/client-routes work that way, you need to load some page before they can be applied. In this case Gatsby must be including those on all pages, including 404.js. I found the same code as you to use in 404.js - it shouldn't be flashing...